# open Source CRM software written in Java

Tags: java, open-source, crm

Can any one suggest me the best and reliable CRM Software which is Open Source written Java technologies.

Before I posted this question i did some Search google and Stackoverflow, I am getting the PHP based CRM but I am particularly looking for Java Technology. thanks in dvance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I got the following links

[InsideCRM](http://www.insidecrm.com/features/top-open-source-solutions-121307/)

[Java Source - Open Source ERP & CRM Software](http://java-source.net/open-source/erp-crm)

[manageability.org](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-crm)

- [Hipergate](http://www.hipergate.org/) - Intranet CRM, sales automation, customer service, email marketing, content management, bug tracker, project manager, groupware, calendar, forums, file sharing, directory. Based on Java /JSP for PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server.
- [OFBiz](http://ofbiz.apache.org/) - The Open For Business Project is an open source enterprise automation software project licensed under the MIT Open Source License. By open source enterprise automation we mean: Open Source ERP, Open Source CRM, Open Source E-Business / E-Commerce, Open Source SCM, Open Source MRP, Open Source CMMS/EAM, and so on.
- [Ohioedge](http://www.ohioedge.com/) - Ohioedge CRM Server is an online CRM application designed for $2-500M organizations requiring centralized, multi-functional, enterprise-wide coordination of sales generation (contact management) & fulfillment (business process/workflow management) activities.
- [Compiere](http://www.compiere.com/) - Smart ERP+CRM solution for Small-Medium Enterprises in the global marketplace covering all areas from customer management, supply chain and accounting. For $2-200M revenue companies looking for "brick and click" first tier functionality..
- [CentricCRM](http://www.concursive.com/) - Centric CRM is a mature, fully featured, Java-based, Web-delivered CRM with contacts, pipeline, accounts, and campaign management, project management, help desk, and admin modules.
- CentraView - CentraView delivers browser based Contact Management, Salesforce Automation (SFA), and Customer Relationship Management (CRM). CentraView is an Enterprise Java (J2EE) application, that runs on Apache Tomcat, JBoss, and uses the MySQL database by default.
- Daffodil CRM - Daffodil CRM's features include integrated email campaigns, customizable views, powerful filtering and automatic mail attachment facility. The One$DB Open Source database provides its back-end.
- openCRX - Features include account management, complex legal entities, leads/opportunities tracking, quotes/sales orders, invoices, territory management, complex product catalogs, product pricing/discounting and activity/task management.
- SourceTap - SourceTap's CRM application is a highly flexible Sales Force Automation (SFA). In supports standard SFA functionality such as lead, account and opportunity management. In addition it includes Sales Management providing sales reps the capability to develop accurate forecasts, seamlessly share information across sales teams, and configure products and services. Based on OFBiz components.
- Cream - A CRM designed specifically to meet the needs of media organizations. Cream is designed to meet the unique demands publishers have, including features that allow subscription management, support for multiple products (print subscriptions, advertising, online subscriptions, books, etc.), customer communications (both incoming and outgoing), and easy-to-use reporting and analytical functions.
- Queplix - QueWeb Customer Care solution that focuses specifically on the portion of the Customer Relationship after the Customer has been acquired. The solution is a J2EE application that uses Google Web Toolkit (GWT) for its UI.
- Openbravo - Openbravo includes all functionality you would expect of an ERP solution, as well as basic CRM and Business Intelligence. Most of the Openbravo code is automatically generated based on a Data Model Dictionary. The Data Model Dictionary is an extension of Compiere.
- Loopfuse - LoopFuse is a marketing and sales automation suite providing organizations the ability to generate leads from their website, score and route leads, marketing campaign capabilities, full web analytics support. LoopFuse also offers the capability to measure ROI within marketing and sales department initiatives. Loopfuse is built on Hibernate, Quartz, JSF and JAAS. It provides plugins for SalesForce.com, SugarCRM and CentricCRM
- JFire - JFire is a customizable ERP and CRM that is based on J2EE 1.4, JDO 2.0 and Eclipse RCP 3.2
- Eberom - Eberom is a CRM and Project Management solution is built using Tomcat and MySQL. It uses Hibernate, Spring, Struts, Jasper Reports and POI HSSF
- Adempiere - The Adempiere project was created in after a disagreement between Compiere Inc., the developers of Compier, and the community that formed around that project

Comment: The last link is useful for find open source packages for all sorts of uses, not just CRM.

Comment: @ Peter I have added few more, can you suggest me which is very easier to use and configure

Answer (score 11):

[OpenCRX](http://www.opencrx.org/) is good looking and has mobile support, also probably the most popular open source CRM in Java.

If you want a broader ERP functionality and tighter integration, [Openbravo ERP](http://www.openbravo.com) is a choice, however its CRM functionality seems to be basic.

Answer (score -8):

Your best choice for open source CRM in Java is Alfresco: http://www.alfresco.com/

Comment: Can you describe the reasons? Alfresco is primarily an ECM (Enterprise Content Management) and WCM (Web Content Management). I'm confused how it can be used as a CRM.

Comment: user1777024 confused between in CMS and CRM..yes, alfresco is document management system not customer relationship management software