# Reusing an Open Source CRM

Tags: open-source, crm

I am looking into creating a simplified version of a CRM without having to reinvent the wheel on some of the base functionality.

Would you please recommend an open source CRM product that I could use?

NOTE: I would be interested in solutions with PHP or Java.

Comment: CRM is not the same as CMS - why is this tagged as both CRM and CMS?

Comment: Agreed. Sorry about the confusion.  I have modified the tags.

Comment: this can save you some time: don't even consider to use vtiger crm, it has the worst code ever.

Comment: Has anyone every tried to use http://www.fatfreecrm.com/?

Comment: Fat Free CRM looks great, if you're OK with a Ruby/Rails solution.

Comment: question is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531321/open-source-crm-software-written-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at SugarCRM?  It's pretty mature so it might not meet your "simplified" qualifier, but if I were in your shoes I'd probably consider starting there.  It started life as an open-source project and there is still a "community edition".

Consider, however, that I have little familiarity with CRM in specific, so I can't comment one way or another on the quality of SugarCRM.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

For me VTECRM 4 is the best! It's based on sugar and vtiger crm and it's easy to use. You can download it and customize. It's based on php - mysql and it's free. dowload link: http://code.google.com/p/vtecrm/source/checkout

Answer (score 0):

If you want a *simplifed* CRM, SugarCRM is NOT the place to start.

Have a look at [Tine2.0](http://www.tine20.org/). It has a demo online, it's built with PHP and ExtJS (so it feels like a desktop application) and is very easy to modify, and has a sizable community behind it (though the owner had the "vision" to [split it by language](http://www.tine20.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=14), so unless you read German well, you'll have to use Google translate most of the time)

It doesn't do Gantt charts, but it does tagging.