# Creating a simple informal CRM tool

Tags: java, .net, database, eclipse, crm

I was wondering if anyone could give me any advice to this project I have been given for the next week and a half.

The goal is to make a simple, informal windows CRM application with database to record customer call times, names, company name, follow up time, etc.

I was planning to create it in Java, do I need to create an installer/installation exe file/build using maven? Or would MS .Net be a better application to create it?

I need a search functionality which will search all entries to the database for key word, then pull back the information, i.e. if Joe rang with an enquiry about his order, assistant could search for "Joe" and pull back all rows with Joe in it, and assistant can see what the order was from the data displayed.

The System also needs to have a username and password to log in. For the meantime, saving the database locally is ok, but then maybe branch onto saving the database to the public drive then have different logins for staff members.

Do you think this kind of project would be feasible in the time frame, or any advice for my approach for development/structure of database?

Can this all be done simpler with MS Access?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://crm-software-review.toptenreviews.com/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531321/open-source-crm-software-written-in-java

Comment: Is it a requirement to build a stand alone application? Why not a web based system?

Comment: Yeah i think they would prefer to have just a standalone application, they have servers here with a networked file system so I assume I could probably stick a database on that... although I'm not entirely sure how to do that just yet! I'm not sure that Java is the right platform to use either, at college I used .NET to create windows application with client-server architecture using the entity model framework, perhaps that is better than swing? Could the web based system approach be a better option in the long run i.e. Java Web App with REST and MVC? I have 1.5 weeks :S Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks too Aubin, if you had this project would you take the code for an existing CRM such as openCRX and try to adapt it for the requirements? Or is it easier to start from scratch and build my own? Its just a simple application they are looking for.

Comment: Or perhaps this whole thing can be done with Microsoft Access?